# write js variable to specific html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write js variable (tab.url.toString()) to html.
I've tried to do this:

```
document.write(tab.url.toString())
```

but it's a part of a big js code and only this is related to html.

The html is called history.html and I wrote there:

```
<script src="nameFile.js"></script>
```

how can I connect between the js code and this specific html file?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'specific html file'. You add stuff to the DOM.

Comment: That specific HTML file would then have to execute the Javascript. You cannot "pass" JS from one page to another.

Comment: can't I save the variable and pass it to the html?

Comment: You can store it in `localStorage` for example, which you can then read on the target page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and grab the element by its id in your Javascript file

```
someId = document.getElementById('someId')
```

Then you append the value to it by

```
let val = tab.url.toString()
someId.innerHTML = val
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create variable on the global window object

You can create a property on the `window` object, something like this:

```js
window.tabUrl = tab.url.toString();
```

This variable is globally accessable by every script that comes after its execution.
As long as you always write the full name `window.tabUrl` it will be available from anywhere.

You can use that value now in other scripts. Just as an example:

```js
document.getElementById('exampleId').innerHTML = window.tabUrl;
```

Documentation for innerHTML:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Using global variables on the `window` object should not be used too much, but it is an easy solution to transfer values for your personal projects.

Comment: Changes to the window object don't persist between requests.

Comment: Oh right I understood different HTML files as templates somehow. Nevermind : )